# How to use QUERY to show data in Google Sheet using tags

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, search

I have a Google Sheet with 2 sheets. In sheet 01 I have this table.

[image]

In sheet 02 I want to have a "Search by Tag" sheet. So, googling I got this formula

`=QUERY('01'!A2:D4, "select B,C,D where A = 'Yellow' order by B")`

[image]

But I have 2 problems here:

1.- I need the formula to take the data from `A2`, under "Search Tag". As you can see, I have to write directly the tag name into the formula.

2.- I need the formula to find at least one of the tags in the same cell. For example, if I look for "red", it will show "Red Computer" data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Sheet 02 you should use:

- **cell A2**: (`Your Search Tag`)
- **cell B2**: `=QUERY('01'!A2:D4, "select B,C,D where A like '%"&A2&"%' order by B",0)`

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you a lot.

Comment: I'm trying to improve this formula. I did this 

**=QUERY({01!A2:H1000;02!A2:H1000}, "select B,C,D where lower(A) like '%"&lower(A2)&"%' order by B",0)**

I'm trying to take info from 2 sheets, so in this formula the Search Tag sheet would be number 03, but I get a #VALUE! error. Why? Is it possible to do this from 2 sheets at the same time?

Comment: And, as a plus, can I add a tag to the results according to the sheet name they came from? Ex. Sheet 01 is called Products, and Sheet 02 is called Services. So, I search for the tag "house" that is for "Red Computer" and "Housekeeping". In the results, can I get an extra column with the name of the Sheet next to each item.

EX: Red Computer / Sheet 01. Housekeeping / Sheet 02. Thanks for the help

Comment: What you are asking for in your comments is a completely different request from the original one. For clarity and consistency reasons, I suggest you create a new question and look for an answer there. This time do include a link to a sample spreadsheet along with the desired result. _(It is a good practice to exersize)_

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF` with a `REGEXMATCH` function or `FILTER` for the same result without `QUERY`.

If you really want a Query, here's a fix :
1 -

Try this instead

```
=QUERY('01'!A2:D4, "select B,C,D where A = '"&A2&"' order by B")
```

2-

Can you explain your needs a little more, with a screenshot of expected result perhaps ?

Answer (score 0):

- paste this in **B1** cell:

  ```
  =QUERY(01!A:D, "select B,C,D where lower(A) contains '"&LOWER(A2)&"' order by B", 1)
  ```